# jQuery Mobile UI and URL Framing screen is rendering too small on Mobile device

Tags: jquery-ui, url, mobile, jquery-mobile

I'm using URL Framing to show my web-app instead of the nasty EC2 web address.  However, when I try and look at the screen using on a mobile device using URL framing, the window size is very large, much much larger than the phone.  If I don't use URL framing, then the screen is much smaller and zoomed in. I'm assuming when I resize the window, it's getting the size of a frame and not my actual browser window on the phone.

How can I still use URL framing and get the window size to be the width/height of my phone?

This is the ugly screen:
[image: This is the ugly screen]

This is what I want it to look like:
[image: This is what I want the screen to look like]

Comment: Have you looked into setting-up a domain name on your EC2 instance? I haven't used AWS in a while but I think `Route 53` is the panel in the AWS admin that does this. Also, are you using a proper `meta-viewport` tag that specifies `width=device-width`?

Comment: I am using a meta-viewport. In my file, the line is `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`  I haven't tried setting up the domain on EC2.  I'll see if that works.

Comment: @Jasper Thanks, using Route 53 and EC2 as my DNS servers did the trick. If you answer it in the answer section, I will approve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jasper mentioned in the comments, using Route 53 and EC2 as the DNS servers did the trick.